# C++ Templates Error: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I get the error mentioned here:
[C++ Templates Error: no matching function for call std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052027/c-templates-error-no-matching-function-for-call-stdvectorint-stdallocat)

Here is the error(again):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<int>::foo(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
main.cpp:21:21: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:14:6: note: void Test<T>::foo(std::vector<T>&) [with T = int]
main.cpp:14:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’ to ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&’
```

The problem is that I have a more complex situation and I don't know how to solve it (without breaking too much code).
I have a Binary Search Tree class that is generic. I want to populate a vector of elements of type T(generic) with all the values from the binary search tree nodes - so I can't make the vector const. The function that traverses the tree is recursive.

So I have:

```
/*main*/

BST<int> t;

t.add(21);
t.add(12);
//.... etc.

vector<int> elements;

t.inorder(elements);
/* ------------ */
```

and:

```
/*BST.h*/
template<typename T>
class BST{
    //....
    Node<T>* root;
    //....
    void inorder_rec(Node<T>* root, vector<T>& result);
    void inorder(vector<T>& result);
    //....
};

template<typename T>
void BST<T>::inorder_rec(Node<T>* root, vector<T>& result){
    // recursive call for the child nodes
}

void BST<T>::inorder(vector<T>& result){
    inorder_rec(this->root, result);
}
/* ------------ */
```

Comment: You should post the actual error you get. Also, I think you are missing `class` in the `BST` class declaration.

Comment: Where is `Test<T>::foo(std::vector<T>&)` ?

Comment: and your member functions need return types.

Comment: I wrote the code posted here really fast because I was in a hurry. The problem is that the code istoo large and I wanted to post just the essential part.

Comment: Posting the essential part is certainly what you should do, but you should make sure it reproduces the error you are reporting, and isn't plagued with other errors that hide the one you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call a function that takes a reference with a temporary. A temporary can only bind to a reference to const. Also, it would be wise to show, where the error actually originated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code? The definitions of inorder and inorder_rec need to have return types. Otherwise, this part of the code looks fine, no temporary in sight:

```
vector<int> elements;
t.inorder(elements);
```

Dumb question, but did you save your file? Or is this error coming from a different part of the code?

Comment: I edited the code (I wrote it in a hurry - this is not the actual code).

Comment: @user1458849 The error message refers to `Test<T>::foo(vector<T>&)`, and not `BST<T>::inorder(vector<T>&)`. What is your actual error message?