# vector template - 'no match for call' error

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to use templates along with vector in my code the following way:

In my header file:

```
template <typename V>
void changeConfig(char option, vector <V> & arg_in){
        // ....
  }
```

In the source file:

```
vector <int> p = {4};
changeConfig('w' ,p);
```

And this's the error that I get:

/include/config.h: In member function ‘void Cfconfig::changeConfig(char, std::vector<_RealType>&) [with V = int]’:

src/config_test.cpp:10:38:   instantiated from here

/include/config.h:68:25: error: no match for call to ‘(int_vector {aka std::vector}) (std::vector&)’

make: *** [featureconfig_test.o_dbg] Error 1

I tried the suggestions on this thread but none of them seem to work.

[C++ Templates Error: no matching function for call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052644/c-templates-error-no-matching-function-for-call)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Okay, I made a short snippet of my code which gives the same error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;


template <typename V>
void changeConfig(char option, vector <V> & arg_in){

     vector<int> window = {5};
     vector<double> scale = {3};

            switch(option){
                    case 'w':                                        
                            window(arg_in);
                            break;
                    case 's':
                            scale(arg_in);
                            break;
            } 

    }


int main(){

    vector <int> p = {3};
    changeConfig<int>('w', p);

    return 0;

}
```

---

I compiled using :
   g++ -std=c++0x test_template.cpp -o test

which gave me this error:

test_template.cpp: In function ‘void changeConfig(char, std::vector<_RealType>&) [with V = int]’:

test_template.cpp:45:33:   instantiated from here

test_template.cpp:32:33: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector) (std::vector&)’

test_template.cpp:35:33: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector) (std::vector&)’

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using? This compiles fine on gcc 4.6.

Comment: Update your compiler: http://ideone.com/tBsACf

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: `p = {4};` is C++11. Is it availbale/enabled?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled, I just checked the flags on my Makefile:    
CC              = g++ -std=c++0x

Comment: Please provide a snippet that reproduces the error and we can copy, paste, and compile.

Comment: Thank you mfontanini ... my code did compile without the switch statements inside the function. I have edited my original question to include a short snippet which fails to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `window(arg_in);` and `scale(arg_in);`. You are trying to call an `std::vector` like a function with another `std::vector` as an argument. I think you are trying to assign one vector to another, so just use assignment or `swap`.

```
 vector<int> window = {5};
 vector<int> scale = {3}; // Note I changed this from double to int

        switch(option){
                case 'w':                                        
                        window = arg_in; // Perhaps you meant arg_in = window
                        break;
                case 's':
                        scale = arg_in;  // Perhaps you meant arg_in = scale
                        break;
        } 

}
```

If you want to use `vector<double> scale`, use `scale.assign(arg_in.begin(), arg_in.end());` instead or the other way around `arg_in.assign(scale.begin(), scale.end());`.

Comment: How is it in a non-deduced context?

Comment: I tried that too as per the suggestion given on another SO thread.. didn't work :(

Comment: `V` can be deduced without any problem here.

Comment: This is the error that I got:  

In member function ‘void Cfconfig::changeConfig(char, std::vector<_RealType>&) [with V = int]’:

 error: no match for call to ‘(int_vector {aka std::vector<int>}) (std::vector<int>&)’